# onNotification is not triggered when app is in killed state in android

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am able to receive the locally scheduled notifications for both Android and IOS and I am trying to navigate the user to screens according to the type of notification when the user taps on the notification. IOS works fine but on Android when I receive the notification in killed state, then onNotification is not working in some android phones.
It works fine in realme with OS version 13 but not in redme with OS version 13 and vivo with OS version 12.
Kindly help me to fix this issue.

All the permissions are added in AndroidManifest.xml. SplashActivity.java is already added. It works fine on some phones but not working in these Android OS versions.

Answer (score 0):

some of brands such as oppo, vivo and some models of huawei etc kill all processes about applications even google system threads.
in these brands ui customized by company and this implementation is imperfect so these brand's phones kill all processes that running in background after a few second/minute.
you can communicate with company for adding your app their whitelist but I think   to waste your time in this issue.
you can see this problem in recieving mails,other app's notifications.